# assembly 8086 double word subtraction

Tags: assembly, subtraction, emu8086

I need to subtract two double words in assembly 8086 and print result as decimal number on screen. I need to get every of these two double words like variable of size word multiplied with variable of size word.

I wrote this code, but I am not sure am I doing this on right way with double words and signed numbers.

Subtraction is impossible with two memory location, so result of multiplication `min_niz1` with `max_niz1` I put in `minmax1`. Second result of multiplication need to be in `AX` and `DX`, can I write subtraction after that and print in on screen as in my code? 
Would this be correct also for signed words?

```
mov AX,min_niz1
mul max_niz1
push ax
push dx
pop minmax1

mov AX,min_niz2
mul max_niz2

sub DX:AX,minmax1

int 21h
```

Comment: You need two instructions for extended-precision subtraction: `sub ax, [low_word]` / `sbb dx, [high_word]`.  (Where you can use any addressing mode for wherever you put the first `mul` result.  It doesn't have to be memory, if you copied them to `si` and `di` for example.  But anyway, the key point is that in 16-bit x86 assembly, you can't operate on a whole dword at once with a single integer instruction.

Answer (score 1):

> so result of multiplication min_niz1 with max_niz1 I put in minmax1
>
> ```
> mov AX,min_niz1
> mul max_niz1
> push ax
> push dx
> pop minmax1
> ```

The result of the word-sized multiplication is the dword in `DX:AX` that you place on the stack. OK, But the single `pop minmax1` will only put the high word of the product in the variable *minmax1*!

Consider changing the code to:

```
mov ax, min_niz1
mul max_niz1
mov minmax1_low, ax
mov minmax1_high, dx
```

> can I write subtraction after that and print in on screen as in my code?
>
> ```
> sub DX:AX,minmax1
> ```

This subtraction is not a legal instruction.

On [8086](/questions/tagged/8086) you need a chain of subtraction instructions to calculate this difference of 32-bit numbers:

```
sub ax, minmax1_low
sbb dx, minmax1_high
```

> Would this be correct also for signed words?

When dealing with signed words, you would change the `mul` instruction into the `imul` instruction. That will produce signed dwords that you can subtract just as shown above.